# Recreate destintionViewController in prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, swift, dependency-injection

I am trying to find a clean way to handle constructor based dependency injection in a `UIViewController`.  I've created a base `UIViewController` that overrides `prepareForSegue` and in that creates a new segue with my dependency-resolved view controller to pass to `prepareForSegue`.  It looks something like:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let resolvedController = 
        controllerFactory.resolveController(segue.destinationViewController.dynamicType)

    let newSegue = UIStoryboardSegue(identifier: segue.identifier, 
                                     source: segue.sourceViewController, 
                                     destination: resolvedController)

    super.prepareForSegue(newSegue, sender: sender)
}
```

The idea is that all of my view controllers will inherit from this and all segues will go through it.

This, however, does not work.  The code *is* hit via breakpoints and my controller is created properly, but the view does not actually use it.  I understand you aren't able to re-create segues programmatically, as they're directly tied to storyboards.  So, all I really need to do is change the controller in the new segue to my dependency-resolved controller.  Is this possible?

Comment: the `destinationViewController` peroperty of UIStoryboardSegue is readonly so I doubt this is possible, even with a subcalss of UIStoryBoardSegue. Why not override `PushViewController` instead of using Segues? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboardSegue_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIStoryboardSegue/destinationViewController

Comment: @pnavk correct, this is why I was trying to re-create the segue.  I will look into `PushViewController`, but will that help using storyboards?